# On Duplicate Key Update - Multiple Columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

When using [insert... on duplicate key update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), what is the syntax to update multiple columns?

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (’$val1’, ‘$val2’, ‘$val3’, ‘$val4’)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2=‘$val2’, col3=‘$val3’, col4=‘$val4’ // <-- not sure
```

Update: I am using this within PHP. Since this is a syntax question, it very relevant.

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4) 
                         VALUES (’$val1’, ‘$val2’, ‘$val3’, ‘$val4’)
                         ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (col2=‘$val2’, col3=‘$val3’, col4=‘$val4’)")
```

Again, not sure about this last part with the "Update".

Answer (score 53):

Well, this is old. But of course you only need to provide a value *once*, there's no reason to add it a second time in the query (which comes in handy for multiple inserts, or prepared statements):

```
INSERT INTO table1
  (col1, col2, col3, col4)
VALUES
  ('val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  col2=VALUES(col2),
  col3=VALUES(col3) [,...]
```

Which has as advantage it will still work for a multiple insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO table1
  (col1, col2, col3, col4)
VALUES
  ('val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4'),
  ('val5', 'val6', 'val7', 'val8'),
  ('val9', 'val10', 'val11', 'val12')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  col2=VALUES(col2),
  col3=VALUES(col3) [,...]
```

A modern PHP example:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        col2=VALUES(col2),
        col3=VALUES(col3),
        col4=VALUES(col4)";
$db->prepare($sql)->execute([$val1, $val2, $val3, $val4]);
```

Comment: This is the best answer, just use MySQL's functionality which supports multiple inserts

Comment: This won't work without a comma after `col2=VALUES(col2)`.

Comment: @wortwart Fixed :)

Comment: This should be at the top. Short, concise and easy to understand by example. Didn't even know we could reference values by column/field name till now.

Answer (score 34):

```
INSERT INTO table1
  (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`)
VALUES
  ('val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  `col2`='val2',
  `col3`='val3', [...]
```

I fixed your quotes and tickmarks.

Comment: see my update, this is within php script, hence the syntax. I'd appreciate it if you could take a look now. thanks

Comment: you cannot use tickmarks for values, those are meant to be used with column names. use the syntax i showed on my answer. it will work.

Comment: $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1 (’col1’, ’col2’, ’col3’, ’col4’) VALUES (".$val1.", ".$val2.", ".$val3.", ".$val4.")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ’col2’=".$val2.", ’col3’=".$val3.", ’col4’=".$val4.")

Comment: this is not working :( I know that previously I did NOT have to use tickmarks or quotes for the column names

Comment: okay, you had an extra quotation mark at the end. but this is still not working, I don't know what's wrong :(

Comment: $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1 (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`) VALUES ('".$val1."', '".$val2."', '".$val3."', '".$val4."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `col2`='".$val2."', `col3`='".$val3."', `col4`='".$val4."'"); i made a mistake! those were not tickmarks! this has to work

Comment: how about using pdo::quote()?

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO tb (name, date, stat1, stat2, stat3) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stat1 = stat1 + VALUES(stat1),
                        stat2 = stat2 + VALUES(stat2), 
                        stat3 = stat3 + VALUES(stat3)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of clear syntax there's another syntax form;

```
INSERT INTO `table1` SET `id`=$id,
                         `col2`='$col2',
                         `col3`='$col3'[, ...]
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `col2`='$col2',
                         `col4`='$col4'[, ...]
```

Example;

```
INSERT INTO customers SET cid=10,
                          createdon=NOW(),
                          createdby='user',
                          cname='Steve'
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE modifiedon=NOW(),
                          modifiedby='user',
                          cname='Steve';
```

If there does not exist a customer with ID=10 in database it will be created and columns cid, createdon, createdby, cname will be set. If it does exist, then it will be updated and columns modifiedon, modifiedbym, cname will be updated.

NOTE#1: IF you put for primary key cid=0 here, it will fire AUTO_INCREMENT (of course, if pk column is defined as AUTO_INCREMENT) and a record will be inserted!

NOTE#2: ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE makes update for existing PK ID record. But also it makes update if DUPLICATE is made on any UNIQUE KEY column. For example, if you defined that cname column is UNIQUE, then saving record with cname='Steve' that already exist will result in UPDATE of that record (not new INSERT). Take care about this because you may expect that DB returns error for UNIQUE KEY constraint violation which will not happened here.

Answer (score -1):

Your query seems to be correct.
Here is my example of this type of query:

```
INSERT INTO Stat (id, month, year, views, redirects, onList, onMap, emails) VALUE ("' . $Id . '","' . $month . '","' . $year . '",0,0,"' . $data['onList'] . '","' . $data['onMap'] . '",0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE onList=onList+' . $data['onList'] . ', onMap=onMap+' . $data['onMap']
```

Comment: why is the second `onList` necessary in `onList=onList+'.$data['onList'].`? isn't it enough to have `onList=$data['onList']`? or in my example: `col2='$val2'`?

Comment: what he's doing is slightly different, he's adding $data['onList'] to the onList field value.