# ON DUPLICATE UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

There are several threads about this on SO and other forums. But, I didn't clear about few things when I would like to do a insert query in MySQL. I found [a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991593/on-duplicate-key-update-multiple-columns) which is interesting and quite similar question. But, I would like hear a good suggestions from you.

1. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE- Is this only refer the primary key or other columns of table?
2. If other then I have another questions. Suppose, I have a table something like following columns-

`log_id (PRIMARY KEY`, `user_id (FOREIGN KEY)`, `working_date`, `time_in`, `time_out`

`Scenario:`

1. On `2014-05-04`, Mr. Bin (user_id: 2) checkin at office at `09:03:12 AM`
2. On `2014-05-04`, Mr. Bin (user_id: 2) checkout at office at `03:13:12 PM`

At this point, I wanna to update the existing row which already created at morning for user_id: 2 on same date. I just want to add the checkout time.

`Which I already tried:`

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO work_log (user_id, working_date, time_out) 
VALUES('2', '2014-05-04', '03:13:12')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user_id = VALUES(user_id), working_date = VALUES(working_date)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a composite key like:

```
UNIQUE KEY( user_id, working_date )
```

And in the `ON DUPLICATE`, set values like:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
    UPDATE time_out = VALUES(time_out);
```