# How to combine these queries to achieve faster performance?

Tags: php, mysql

Any way to combine the following queries, or some of them? My goal is to achieve faster performance with fewer inserts. However I don't know how to handle the ON `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE new_table.pages=VALUES(pages)` where I will insert more than 2 variables.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO new_table (hash, pages)
SELECT hash, COUNT( id ) AS pages
FROM behaviour GROUP BY hash
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE new_table.pages=VALUES(pages)");


mysql_query("INSERT INTO new_table (hash, visits)
SELECT hash, visits from audience
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE new_table.visits=audience.visits");


mysql_query("INSERT INTO new_table (hash, first_visit)
SELECT hash, timestamp from audience
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE new_table.first_visit=audience.timestamp");


mysql_query("INSERT INTO new_table (hash, last_visit)
SELECT hash, max(timestamp) from behaviour
group by hash
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE new_table.last_visit=VALUES(last_visit)");


mysql_query("INSERT INTO new_table (hash, goals)
SELECT alerts_data_hash, COUNT( * ) AS goals
FROM alerts_data
WHERE alerts_data_status =  'goal'
GROUP BY alerts_data_hash
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE new_table.goals=VALUES(goals)");
```

Comment: you could use a multi-query by switching over to the mysqli_ api; that's one option and that api could be slightly faster than mysql_. Might not solve the question but will help reduce your code a tad.

Comment: Plain `mysql_` has been deprecated for some time anyway. You should be jumping to `mysqli_` family of functions

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly good, because i am a dog person!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will combine the first 4 queries

```
INSERT INTO new_table (hash, pages, visits, first_visit, last_visit, goals)
SELECT A.hash, COUNT(B.id), A.visits, A.timestamp, MAX(B.timestamp), 0
FROM audience A
LEFT OUTER JOIN behaviour B ON B.hash = A.hash
GROUP BY A.hash
```

I'm not sure if the last one can be a `join` or would have to be a union/separate query.

Comment: what about the "duplicate key" line?

Comment: Ah, forgot that bit. However you can, after the `GROUP BY`, add `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE new_table.pages=VALUES(pages), new_table.visits=a.visits, etc`. Here is another post about updating multiple columns on a duplicate key insert: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991593/on-duplicate-key-update-multiple-columns