# Any way to optimize this query since I only update the table instead of inserting new rows?

Tags: mysql

The structure of the `new_table` is that it will never insert new rows, but will only update the existing ones.

Currently I am using the following query. Is there any way to optimize this (in terms of performance) to achieve faster updates of the rows?

```
INSERT INTO new_table (hash, pages, visits, last_visit)
   SELECT A.hash, COUNT(B.id), A.visits, MAX(B.timestamp)
      FROM audience A
JOIN behaviour B ON B.hash = A.hash
GROUP BY A.hash
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      new_table.pages=VALUES(pages), 
      new_table.visits=VALUES(visits), 
      new_table.last_visit=VALUES(last_visit)
```

Comment: can you show us the output from the SELECT part like : **EXPLAIN SELECT A.hash, COUNT(B.id), A.visits, MAX(B.timestamp)
      FROM audience A
JOIN behaviour B ON B.hash = A.hash
GROUP BY A.hash**

Comment: Have you tried an `UPDATE...JOIN`?

Comment: Do all Cat haters expect others to do all their work for free http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468765/how-to-combine-these-queries-to-achieve-faster-performance

Comment: @BerndBuffen I have updated my question with the image. thank you

Comment: @shmosel using Update i know how to assign values like `column = $variable`

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos - is there really only 1 row in table audience and 6044 rows in table behaviour with the same hash value. can you also show the create of both tables

Comment: @BerndBuffen well that was the result of it.... :/

Comment: Why don't you use `UPDATE` if you never need to insert new rows?

Comment: @Barmar Can you show me how? I can do it using PHP, but first I need to select all the `hash` and then update each of them one by one. But I don't think that this is the right way, because I believe there must be a way to achieve this by plain mysql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UPDATE` rather than `INSERT`.

```
UPDATE new_table n
JOIN audience AS a on a.hash = n.hash
JOIN (
    SELECT hash, COUNT(*) AS pages, MAX(timestamp) AS last_visit
    FROM behaviour
    GROUP BY hash) AS b ON b.hash = n.hash
SET n.pages = b.pages, n.visits = a.visits, n.last_visit = b.last_visits
```

Comment: hi again and thank you for this. I tested it and it seems that it works. to be honest, compared with what I had, it was executed 25 seconds faster. 39 vs 14.
So it has a huge impact on the performance!

A question to understand the theory on this: in my example it tries first to insert and then update, and you removed the "insert" part, right?

Comment: Exactly. This just updates, it doesn't waste time trying to insert and then failing over to the update code.

Comment: thank you once again. you have been really helpful. upvote + accepted.