# check specific cols then, update or create a new row, pdo

Tags: php, pdo

Trying to check specific column values before inserting a new row. But a bit confused PDO's `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` so, here is insert function below.

```
public function insert_schedule($user_id, $status, $content, $date, $time, $remarks, $created_at){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO schedules (user_id, status, content, return_date, return_time, remarks, created_at) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user_id, created_at = VALUES(user_id, created_at)";
    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$user_id, $status, $content, $date, $time, $remarks, $created_at]); 
}
```

I want to check `created_at` and `user_id` before insert a new row. if `created_at` already exist on same `user_id` than update that row. else, insert a new row. How can I fix the above function.

Comment: @MarkusZeller The first half of the syntax looks fine. `(columns) VALUES (values)` is a more common syntax than `SET`. But they do need the values for the `UPDATE` portion.

Comment: Do you have a unique column on `user_id` and `created_at`? `ON DUPLICATE KEY` only works for table keys.

Comment: @aynber I updated `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` part in the question, could you please check it?

Comment: No, you need to separate it out. `UPDATE user_id = VALUES(user_id), created_at = VALUES(created_at)`

Comment: @MarkusZeller actually, I didn't ignore it. didn't understand what you mean there. could you please share full function as an example?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html has a bit of information on the proper syntax, but it seems to be lacking an example on multiple columns for the update portion

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714587/mysql-on-duplicate-key-update-for-multiple-rows-insert-in-single-query and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991593/on-duplicate-key-update-multiple-columns show the proper syntax better

Comment: Looking at it... why would you want to update the created_at and user_id to the same thing if those keys exist? The update portion doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't want to update, `created_at` or `user_id`  trying to check those fields before inserting new row. because if there is already same `created_at` and `user_id` then just need to update others rows. if not then insert a new row. @aynber

Comment: Oh, then you want to 1) Make sure that user_id and created_at is a combined unique key, and 2) pass in the REST of the columns in the UPDATE portion, not the ones that stay the same.

Comment: @aynber i can't give unique key, because it's one to many relation. there will be rows same `user_id` but different `created_at` OR same `created_at` and different `user_id` I am really stuck at this point....

Comment: You need a composite unique key. You can create a key by doing `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX user_created_idx ON schedules  (\`user_id\`,\`created_at\`)` This means there can be only 1 row with the same user_id AND created_at.

Comment: let me try it! @aynber

Comment: @aynber what about the final, insert and update queries? could you give me an example for it?

Comment: Once the unique key is created, you should be able to use Markus' answer to insert and update. The INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY will see that there's already a record with that user_id and created_at, and will update the columns you specify instead.

Comment: oh god, thank you so much. `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX user_created_idx ON schedules (`user_id`,`created_at`)` this is literally saved me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the query to:

```sql
INSERT INTO schedules SET user_id=?, status=?, content=?, return_date=?, return_time=?, remarks=?, created_at=?
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status=?, content=?, return_date=?, return_time=?, remarks=?
```

```php
$stmt->execute([
    $user_id, $status, $content, $date, $time, $remarks, $created_at,
    $status, $content, $date, $time, $remarks
]);
```

- Duplicate keys must definded as index.
- Execute needs the values as duplicate keys AGAIN

Comment: thank you, I tried it, but something is off... I can insert new row no problem here. But can't update the columns, if row has `created_at` and `user_id`

Comment: Are you sure you have an index over those fields? At least the user_id? If in doubt, dump your DDL.

Comment: sorry, you lost me there. "index over those fields", could you open it a bit?

Comment: Please read about [index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html).

Comment: Please see my updated answer. The logic was a bit wrong. Let's say the user_id is the unique field, you want to update all other fields. What you don't want to update is the user_id and the created_at. You need to create an UNIQUE index over user_id field.

Comment: yes, put a unique index over `user_id` but still, when I try to update the existed row. still creating new row with same `user_id` and same `created_at`

Comment: Impossible. MySQL would not write a new row when one is duplicate.

Comment: okay, I understand. and now I can update, but as you said before. this is wrong. because this is one to many relation table. so there is more then one same `user_id`

Comment: Hm, maybe the database design is not that optimal?

Comment: ah I thought, in PDO there is a way or method like in eloquent `updateOrCreate` but I guess, no help huh.... it is just no good.... :)

Comment: PDO is a good way to prevent SQL injections, but at the end it is just an interface.

Comment: in comments, -thanks to the aynber- I used `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX user_created_idx ON schedules (user_id,created_at)` then, used the query of yours.. and yes it worked out...